# Adding/Appending per occurrence in string

Tags: python, if-statement, append

I'm working on the Cows/Bulls game, which I know has been answered a thousand times, but I've yet to see this particular method come up, and I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get the count of a list to increase by 1 for every occurrence of a number that exists between two lists, but is not in the same index position.  See example below.

```
n = [1,2,3,4]
solution = [0,3,1,0]
bulls = 0
cows = 0
     
for i in solution:
    if i != n[0]:
        if i in n:
            bulls +=1
            print (bulls)
```

I've also tried writing this the following way with no success.

```
n = [1,2,3,4]
solution = [0,3,1,0]
bulls = [0]
cows = [0]
     
for i in solution:
    if i != n[0] and i in n:
        bulls.append(1)
        bulls = sum(bulls)
        print (bulls)
```

Both of these blocks of code return 1, when by rights they should be returning 2 (1 for the matching 1's in the list, and one for the matching 3's).

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. One of your main problems was that you were telling bulls to be 1 at every iteration of the loop (`bulls = sum(bulls)`). Another problem is you were only checking `n[0]` when you should have been checking `n[currentSolutionIndex]`

```
n = [1,2,3,4]
solution = [0,3,1,0]
bulls = 0
cows = 0
 
for i, data in enumerate(solution):
    if data in n:
        if data != n[i]: #if they aren't the same index
            bulls += 1
        else:            #otherwise they are the same index
            cows += 1
    
print(bulls) #2
print(cows)  #0
```

Here's an alternate example that I am giving you as a way to introduce you to more things. It is not necessarily a good way to handle this problem, but it introduces you to more concepts, and this problem is an easy way to understand them. Using `zip` we can iterate 2 arrays at once. `f1` is the `farm1` value, and `f2` is the `farm2` value. We are also using a list generator so we can keep all of the logic on one line.

There is an important thing to note here ~ `side effects` are bad coding practice. In this case we are using a list generator for the ultimate purpose of parsing a number from it. That is a `side effect`. We should use list generators to get a list. Here we are abusing a list generator for the sole purpose of dumping it into `sum`. In short, none of this example is good as a whole, but taken piecemeal and used responsibly it illustrates some handy concepts.

```
farm1 = [0,2,3,1]
farm2 = [1,2,3,4]

cows = sum([1 for f1, f2 in zip(farm1, farm2) if f1 == f2])
bulls = sum([1 for f1, f2 in zip(farm1, farm2) if f1 != f2 and f1 in farm2])

print(cows)  #2
print(bulls) #1
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just learning python, and this is the first concept I've come across where I got really stuck.  I wasn't aware of the enumerate function, which helps greately.

Comment: @Brandon Covington - I'm glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, please remember to select it as the solution.

Comment: Your answer did, and I just marked it.  It also created a new problem, but only as a result of having to figure out how to append counts when the index positions do match, but that's a different question.

Comment: @Brandon Covington - Thank you, sir. Give me 1 minute, I'll answer your second question here.

Comment: Thank you, the concepts you just showed me are something I've been struggling to understand, and you put them in a way that made them very easy to visualize.  I'm going to add this example of how this language works to my running notes list.  I used this code, and it works perfectly (not to mention saves about 50 lines of code from doing it fully manual.  I sincerely appreciate the help, and I'm going to read up on side effects to understand how they work and how to avoid them.

Comment: @Brandon Covington - if you take the time to understand generators, as-well-as built-ins such as `zip`, `enumerate`, `filter`, `next`, and the behavior of `*args`, `**kwargs` with tricks like `[*kwargs]`, you will become a python wizard. You seem like a sharp individual. You could probably learn all of this in a matter of hours. The only real problem with python is that most of the concepts do not translate to other languages. Even if you went to a language as simple as javascript you would practically have to start over learning how to program. Keep that in mind.